# Can't complete creating a polygon in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

I am using ArcMap 10.7.1.

The problem started suddenly, when creating a polygon. Instead of what ArcMap usually does, which is autocompleting to the first vertex completed, it moves the suggested "end-line" to the second vertex created. In the image above, I would have expected a line to the first vertex created (green) and then autocompleted it. I have no idea why it suddenly make a line to the second vertex (red). What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your Snapping choices?

Comment: Sorry, no. This was for a colleague of mine.